# Session Management System

Tags: php, security, session

I am in the process of creating my own session management system and I want to create my own custom Id before starting the session using session_create_id() function, though I am not sure as to how the prefix works, the problem I am having is if I echo the session_create_id with prefix I will see the pre fix with the session id although when I input this session_create_id into the session_id function I am only seeing the standard 26 length id when echo'ed. This article i found on https://wiki.php.net/rfc/session-create-id does explain why I only see the standard length I have set in my config file. But I am unsure on how I know this prefix is there and essentially if it is actually adding a more secure session_id.

This information from the article which fills some of my curiosity.

NOTE: Prefix length is not considered as a part of session.sid_length. Session ID length became 'prefix length' + session.sid_length. Total length must be less than 256 chars.

Code:

```
//SessionRegeneration
function sess_regenration(){
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){

    //CreateRandomStringForPrefix
    $RandomizerForPreFix = str_split("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    shuffle($RandomizerForPreFix);
    $EmptyStringToAppenRandomizer = '';
    foreach($RandomizerForPreFix as $Element ){
     $EmptyStringToAppenRandomizer .= $Element;
   }
    //CreateNewSessionIdWithPrefix
    $CreatedId = session_create_id($EmptyStringToAppenRandomizer);
    session_id($CreatedId);
    //StartSession
    session_start();
    echo session_id();
  }

}
```

Comment: Note that `shuffle()` is not suitable for cryptographic purposes as [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) already warn. This means the code above is vulnerable, generated session ids are predictable. Any application using this will also likely be vulnerable to session fixation. Such a project is ok for educational purposes, but for real applications, don't roll your own - it's already implemented securely.

Comment: @Gabor Lengyel do you have any recommendations for a proper prefix to use?

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized that in order to use session_create_id() functionality, I must shut off strict mode, Though now I will have an issue with unauthorized session Id's... Is there anyway to be able to create this session Id and still not allow unauthorized sessions.